# When importing sklearn pythonw.exe stops working

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When `from sklearn import *` is executed in IDLE, it pops up that `pythonw.exe has stopped working`. Numpy and Scipy work normally. I have tried to reinstall the package sklearn with "scikit-learn-0.14.1.win32-py2.7.exe" and `scikit-learn-master/setup.py`, but it didn't solve the problem.
Does anyone know how to deal with this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can launch pythonw.exe in a debugger with a script that just runs the offending import statement, and see where it crashes.

Comment: Does it crash even when you import individual modules? (e.g. from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier)

Comment: @AdrienNK: Yes, it does.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: I'm not clear how to launch pythonw.exe in a debugger with a script. But I open the Debug Control window and run a script containing "from sklearn import svm", "'bdb'.run(), line 387: exec cmd in globals, locals   >'__main__'.<module>(), line1:from sklearn import svm" shows up in the Debug Control window.